# export wordpress posts to a mediawiki

Tags: wordpress, import, export, mediawiki

I have a website with Wordpress template, I want to export just all my **posts** and import them to **mediwiki**.
I was wondering, is there any plugin, website or any other especial tool for doing this?
**I also have access to both sql files!**
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is two problems. Export then import. Wordpress has a built in export ability but it may require installation of an official plugin to make full use of it. Check tools in the Wordpress admin menu.

Mediwiki will require it's own PHP and/or XML scripts for importing and I've never used it to help you on that part.

Answer (score 0):

there is a possibility to parse a rss feed or wordpress export file to create a file which you can use with the following program.

http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki_Bulk_Page_Creator

Answer (score 0):

Can you export your posts into HTML?
IF so, just google for "HTML to wiki", for instance: http://labs.seapine.com/htmltowiki.cgi

Just beware that there might be some errors.

Otherwise it is not so hard to implement a converter.

Comment: I installed a plugin and export a txt file, now I want to convert it to mediawiki known xml file!

Comment: In that case I suppose you'll have to implement a converter by yourself, or just google around until you can find a converter that can handle your txt file.

Comment: in fact we did it with a json file witch put the necessary tag to the files.